# WPF touch and slide/drag animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm trying to create a pretty simple WPF interface, and from what I know this should be mostly possible using pure XAML.

**What I know**

I have a pretty basic understanding of WPF so far, however I have a decent grasp on XAML.

I know or can work out how to put content in these panels. This isn't the topic of this question.

**What I don't know**

I don't know how to animate this interface.

I'm not very proficient at binding, however again, that's not the topic of this question.

The topic of this question is what would be the best way to animate panels 1-4 (images below) so that they may be dragged (via touch) into view. The number of panels here may be static for the purpose of this question.

The panels (1-4) can be stack panels, grids or whatever; their content isnt important. What is important is the container that would contain all 4 panels. The complication in this animation is the other two containers here (Item One/TODO), as they're in the way of a smooth animation.

If it makes this question simpler, the touch features can be ignored for now, and a simple button push can slide the containers across.

One
[image]

Two
[image]

Comment: What have you used to make those wireframe mockups? They look nice.

Comment: I used Balsamiq - it's a great tool and I love it :)

Comment: Thanks! You sold it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "moving a rectangle" in this link http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/wpf/IntroductionToWPFAnimations.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Why not use WPF pages instead?
You might wanna consider [this one](http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=280).

> **WPF application which allows you to do 3D page transitions**
>   - You can use this application as a base to build WPF applications in which it is easy to add pages (UserControls) and switch from one to another with three kinds of animations: slide, flip and cube.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to encapsulate a page in a window or other page? As you can see from my diagrams, it's only the panels that i'd like to move, not the whole page.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this (http://bot.codeplex.com/ - Zap Scrollbar) through my own research, which is working very well so far.

This is the control I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this one](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/) too.

This is much simpler (to implement/use) than the other one I've posted.

> **Transitionals** is a framework for building and using WPF transitions which provide an easy way to switch between UI views in a rich and animated way. Think of transitions for applications in the same way you think of transitions for video editing. Wipe, Cut, Dissolve, Star, Blinds and 3D Rotating Cube are all examples of transitions supported by the Transitionals framework.