# WPF touch panel

Tags: wpf, touch

I am looking for a WPF component that is a collection of panels that are side by side and can be flipped trough by touch.
The question was asked before but no real answer came out it it at that time:
[WPF touch and slide/drag animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598827/wpf-touch-and-slide-drag-animation)
(the component the author talks about is no longer to be found)

The behavior I want can also be seen in the Android 4.0 home screen: you have multiple screens side by side and you flip trough them by swiping left or right.

The application I am going to build will run on a touch enabled device.
I am willing to use a commercial product if that exists.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/370650/Simple-Metro-Style-Panorama-Control-for-WPF) is a good start.

Comment: @dowhilefor : thank you for the suggestion, it looks promising.